# Pass data within fragment without using bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, bundle, share

Is it possible to pass data using class object?
as i don't want to use bundle to pass data between fragments can anyone suggest me for the same?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fragments and they belong to the same Activity, just fill the data in the activity. This way both fragments have access to the data ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use interface for exchanging data between activity and fragment as well as between fragments also.